# Right bit shift in C keeps sign for variable int, loses sign for raw int, why?

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift

I am currently trying to find a non-zero integer a such that a >> 31 == 1. The issue I'm running into is that any right shift of a negative number results in a negative number... unless I perform the shift on a raw integer. For example output:

```
int a = -2147483648
a >> 31 = -1
-2147483648 >> 31 = 1
```

At least, this was what I got while messing around with GDB, trying to figure out what's happening.

I've tried other inputs such as 1, -1, 2147483647, etc., but none of them work. I figure I'm probably misunderstanding something about integer representation, but I can't figure out what, and a number of the recommended posts either don't make sense to me or don't answer my question.

Comment: Show us the exact code, and how you check the values. FWIW "*a non-zero integer a such that a >> 31 == 1*" is not possible for signed 32-bit `int`s assuming the shift is arithmetic.

Comment: The only other code I might add is the full statement: `int x = !((!a) | (a >> 31))` such that x must be 0. !a = 0 for all int != 0, as far as I have found, so there must be an int a that satisfies the other condition.

Comment: You are mixing logical and bitwise operations. If you want a bitwise `not`, use `~`.

Comment: That's what the assignment code is *shrug* I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: Notice that `int a = -2147483648` is assigning a type wider than `int` to an `int`.

Comment: `-2147483648` is not an `int`. C does not have negative integer constants; `-2147483648` is actually `2148473648` with a unary `-` operation. Your C implementation probably uses 32 bits for `int`, and 2,147,483,648 is too big for an `int`, so the constant `2147483648` in source code is interpreted as a `long int` or `long long int`. So `-2147483648` is a `long int` or `long long int`, so shifting it may give a different result than shifting the `int` `a` that has the value −2,147,483,648 in it. For details, you need to show actual code and state which C implementation you are using.

Comment: An `int` does not have 32 value bits so you can't shift it by 31 steps. Doing so is undefined behavior. In addition, right shifting negative values has implementation-defined behavior, it could either be arithmetic or logical shift. Just _don't_ use signed operands together with bitwise operators ever - the C language is broken by design in case you do. C has deliberately chosen to make things that are well-defined in any CPU undefined on the C machine abstraction layer. Including shifts and signed overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Right shift on a signed integer is implementation-defined.

Most modern compilers translate it to an arithmetic shift:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I am currently trying to find a non-zero integer a such that a >> 31 == 1.

Since you said *integer* and not `int`, a 32 bit `unsigned int` with the high bit set will satisfy this.

```
unsigned int a = 2147483648;
a = a >> 31;
printf("a=%u\n", a);
```

The above will output 1.